# Two Invoke-Command at the same time

Tags: powershell, foreach, wmic, invoke-command

I'm using this PowerShell script to resume Bitlocker on every active device:

```
Get-Content "clients.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction 0 -Quiet) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
            Resume-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "$_ is OFFLINE" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

But I also want to trigger a hardware inventory via `Invoke-WMIMethod` on every active device with this command:

```
Invoke-WMIMethod -ComputerName $Server -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}"
```

I was able to script the first part but it isn't that well to built in the second command.

Comment: The second code snippet has a spurious trailing curly bracket. With that said, why don't you include the `wmic` command (or an equivalent `*-WmiObject` statement) in the scriptblock of your first code snippet?

Comment: With an `&&` or `|` ?

Comment: Either on a new line or separated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are drifting a bit in the wrong direction. 
When using `Invoke-Command`, it processes the scriptblock, against 32 computers simultaneously (in parallel)!

If you are processing computers with `foreach`, it would handle them sequentially, which would be much slower. 
Same is valid when using *WMI cmdlets. Always try to replace them with the corresponding *CIM* cmdlets, as the same logic applies - computers are being processed in parallel.

Consider something like:

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content -Path Clients.txt
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ScriptBlock {
    Resume-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:"
    #Add second command
    #add third command and so on
}
```

I am not sure, what would be the alternative command to `Invoke-WMIMethod`, when executing locally. Maybe `Set-WMIInstance`, but I am only speculating!
Then if you would like to add second command for execution, just add it into the scriptblock of `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: The reason for replacing WMI cmdlets with CIM cmdlets is not performance. `Get-WmiObject` takes an array of computers and processes it in parallel just like `Get-CimInstance`. In fact, WMI usually provides better performance than CIM. The reason for replacing WMI with CIM is that a) the latter use WinRM instead of DCOM (less firewall headaches) and b) Microsoft has deprecated the WMI cmdlets in favor of CIM.

Comment: I was not sure, if processing was the same with `WMI`, but as being depreciated, as mentioned, it would be always better to go with `CIM`. Thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: And something else to add: Using `CIM` cmdlets, requires to have PowerShell remoting enabled (`Enable-PSRemoting`), as Ansgar stated, because it uses WinRM. While WMI cmdlets, because using DCOM and RPC, does not have this requirement (only local admin priviledges).

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. It would be better with the `$_ is offline` i had in the foreach but its not that important.